# macro to create multiple workbooks from single worksheet by number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

So far I have created a macro to pull 1 row of data from multiple workbooks in a folder into a single .csv worksheet with a stable header section (3 rows).

The next step is to upload the data, however our system will only accept .csv files with a max of 40 rows.

**I need a macro that will create multiple workbooks, each with 40 lines of the data (including headers rows (1-3). There are 157 columns, each row is unique**.

I'm very much still a beginner at VBA so any help will be much appreciated!

Let me know if you need more info from me in order to help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
Sub splitSheet()

    Const maxLines As Integer = 40

    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim rngTemp As Range

    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range("A1", wsTarget.Range("A" & wsTarget.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).EntireRow

    Set rngTemp = wsTarget.Range("1:" & maxLines)

    Do
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Worksheets.Add

        rngTemp.Copy
        wsNew.Paste

        Set rngTemp = rngTemp.Offset(maxLines, 0)

    Loop Until Intersect(rngTemp, rngTarget) Is Nothing

End Sub
```